# Spark 2.0 - Dataset<Row> Write to Parquet in Java

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I want to write Dataset into a Parquet file in **Java**, I use

```
Dataset<Row> ds = getDataFrame();
ds.write().parquet("data.parquet");
```

This code is run by spark-submit command as given below

```
sudo spark-submit --class getdata --master yarn --num-executors 4 --executor-cores 1 --jars guava-14.0.1.jar,hadoop-common-2.7.3.jar,hbase-client-1.3.0.jar,hbase-common-1.3.0.jar,hbase-protocol-1.3.0.jar,log4j-1.2.17.jar,metrics-core-2.2.0.jar,ojdbc6.jar,spark-core_2.11-2.0.2.jar,spark-assembly.jar,spark-sql_2.11-2.0.2.jar,hive-beeline-1.2.1.spark2.jar,hive-cli-1.2.1.spark2.jar,hive-exec-1.2.1.spark2.jar,hive-jdbc-1.2.1.spark2.jar,hive-metastore-1.2.1.spark2.jar,parquet-column-1.7.0.jar,parquet-common-1.7.0.jar,parquet-encoding-1.7.0.jar,parquet-format-2.3.0-incubating.jar,parquet-generator-1.7.0.jar,parquet-hadoop-1.7.0.jar,parquet-hadoop-bundle-1.6.0.jar,parquet-hive-1.0.1.jar,parquet-jackson-1.7.0.jar,spark-hive_2.11-2.0.2.jar getdata.jar
```

I get the following exception.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.apache.spark.sql.sources.DataSourceRegister: Provider org.apache.spark.sql.hive.orc.DefaultSource could not be instantiated
```

What am I missing? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

A ServiceLoader finds DefaultSource implementations on the classpath invokes a constructor that returns a type which doesn't correspond to the expected return type.

An OrcRelation is returned where a HadoopFsRelation is expected, but OrcRelation doesn't implement HadoopFsRelation. It might be a version conflict, since I can't find HadoopFsRelation in 2.1.0, while it is there in older versions (e.g. 1.6.0).

Do you have multiple Spark versions on your classpath, or mixed Spark/Hive implementations?

Comment: I use only spark 2.0.2. Which jar file do I need to include in spark-submit command to make it work?